# How do I debug why stderr is being suppressed?

Tags: bash, zsh, io-redirection, stderr

Running some shell functions and ctrl-c-ing them leads to my stderr being suppressed, such that `echo hi >&2` and `echo hi > /dev/stderr` print nothing. I want to debug this, but I have no idea how to start. How can I check where stderr is redirected to? Doing a `exec zsh` doesn't solve this problem in an affected shell, which indicates the problem is indeed with a rogue redirection.

I'm on macOS.

I tried:

```
ll /dev/fd
crw--w---- 0,11 evar 12 May 18:32 0
crw--w---- 0,11 evar 12 May 18:32 1
crw-rw-rw-  0,2 root 12 May 18:32 2
```

Perhaps the issue is that `/dev/fd/2` is somehow owned by `root`?

Update:

```
lsof -p $$
COMMAND   PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE  SIZE/OFF                NODE NAME
zsh     69568 evar  cwd    DIR    1,6      1472          8624004142 /Users/evar/Base/Lectures
zsh     69568 evar  txt    REG    1,6    618652          8678375637 /usr/local/Cellar/zsh/5.8/bin/zsh
zsh     69568 evar  txt    REG    1,6    452676          8677805768 /usr/local/Cellar/pcre/8.44/lib/libpcre.1.dylib
zsh     69568 evar  txt    REG    1,6    312924          8678370072 /usr/local/Cellar/ncurses/6.2/lib/libncursesw.6.dylib
zsh     69568 evar  txt    REG    1,6    251160          8678375669 /usr/local/Cellar/zsh/5.8/lib/zsh/zle.bundle
zsh     69568 evar  txt    REG    1,6    123012          8678375645 /usr/local/Cellar/zsh/5.8/lib/zsh/complete.bundle
zsh     69568 evar  txt    REG    1,6     65188          8678375676 /usr/local/Cellar/zsh/5.8/lib/zsh/compctl.bundle
zsh     69568 evar  txt    REG    1,6     18220          8678375661 /usr/local/Cellar/zsh/5.8/lib/zsh/terminfo.bundle
zsh     69568 evar  txt    REG    1,6     27888          8678375680 /usr/local/Cellar/zsh/5.8/lib/zsh/system.bundle
zsh     69568 evar  txt    REG    1,6     17240          8678375681 /usr/local/Cellar/zsh/5.8/lib/zsh/langinfo.bundle
zsh     69568 evar  txt    REG    1,6     38064          8678375656 /usr/local/Cellar/zsh/5.8/lib/zsh/parameter.bundle
zsh     69568 evar  txt    REG    1,6     22864          8678375674 /usr/local/Cellar/zsh/5.8/lib/zsh/pcre.bundle
zsh     69568 evar  txt    REG    1,6     37588          8678375667 /usr/local/Cellar/zsh/5.8/lib/zsh/zutil.bundle
zsh     69568 evar  txt    REG    1,6     62316          8678375647 /usr/local/Cellar/zsh/5.8/lib/zsh/complist.bundle
zsh     69568 evar  txt    REG    1,6     22620          8678375675 /usr/local/Cellar/zsh/5.8/lib/zsh/stat.bundle
zsh     69568 evar  txt    REG    1,6     29076          8678375649 /usr/local/Cellar/zsh/5.8/lib/zsh/zpty.bundle
zsh     69568 evar  txt    REG    1,6     18736          8678375668 /usr/local/Cellar/zsh/5.8/lib/zsh/datetime.bundle
zsh     69568 evar  txt    REG    1,6     17628          8678375660 /usr/local/Cellar/zsh/5.8/lib/zsh/zleparameter.bundle
zsh     69568 evar  txt    REG    1,6     18208          8678375654 /usr/local/Cellar/zsh/5.8/lib/zsh/termcap.bundle
zsh     69568 evar  txt    REG    1,6     63728          8678375662 /usr/local/Cellar/zsh/5.8/lib/zsh/computil.bundle
zsh     69568 evar  txt    REG    1,6     22440          8678375673 /usr/local/Cellar/zsh/5.8/lib/zsh/sched.bundle
zsh     69568 evar  txt    REG    1,6   1534352 1152921500311885154 /usr/lib/dyld
zsh     69568 evar    0u   CHR  16,11   0t56261                3469 /dev/ttys011
zsh     69568 evar    1u   CHR  16,11   0t56261                3469 /dev/ttys011
zsh     69568 evar    2w   CHR    3,2 0t1314232                 314 /dev/null
zsh     69568 evar   10u   CHR  16,11   0t21049                3469 /dev/ttys011
zsh     69568 evar   11u   CHR   15,9    0t9086                 583 /dev/ptmx
```

Comment: Try `lsof`. macOS may have some macOS-specific way to do it as well.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I posted the result of `lsof`. I guess `zsh     69568 evar    2w   CHR    3,2 0t1314232                 314 /dev/null` means that `2` is now null. Any idea on how I can debug what sets it off? A hook or sth?

Comment: Doing `set -x` or running `zsh -x` might help. You won't see the `exec 2> /dev/null`, as xtrace output goes to stderr, but you'll see the last messages before that  which may give you a clue as to what does the `exec 2> /dev/null`.

Comment: So did you figure out what was redirecting stderr? [Somebody just reported the same issue in a duplicate question](/q/587425)

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I did, though not by setting `set -x`. I hate that beast. :D I reported the issue [here](https://github.com/sindresorhus/pure/issues/547). It seems to be fixed in the new version.

Answer (score 3):

The usual way of obtaining the information is the normal BSD command

```
fstat -p $$
```

but your listing of `/dev/fd` already has enough to tell you that file descriptor 2 is not connected to the terminal character device that file descriptors 0 and 1 are.  The major and minor numbers of files under `/dev/fd` are somewhat complex to grasp, but they do tell you, in conjunction with the permissions and owners, that there is a difference here.

Sans explicit redirection, processes running in a terminal login session will have all three descriptors referencing the same (terminal) character device.  File descriptors 0 and 1 are clearly *still* referencing your terminal character device, owned by you and only readable and writable by you, as is common for terminal devices in login sessions.

Standard error *has not* been "suppressed".  Writes to it are still happening, and are being sent to a character device of some kind, which you do not own but to which you have write access.  Almost certainly that character device that file descriptor 2 references is `/dev/null`, and you've *sourced* a script that redirected standard error to `/dev/null` with something like

```
exec 2>/dev/null
```

So, after checking to see what `fstat` tells you just to expand your knowledge, redirect it back again.

```
exec 2>&1
```